# Is there mathematical gamma function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, calculator, gamma-function

I'd like to make a scientific calculator in C#, but I didn't find gamma function to 
calculate fractal factorials. 
The function's description is below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

How can I reach gamma function in C#?

Comment: Looks like there is a 3rd party library that does this, see [here](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/functions.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the [Math.NET package from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/)

Documentation on the Gamma Function : https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Functions.html

Comment: Thanks, it was a very useful information. And you didn't vote down my question, like other people here. :D

Comment: Here is a working documentation link:
https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Functions.html

Answer (score 3):

The `Math.NET` package is indeed an easy way to get the gamma function.  Please keep in mind that `gamma(x)` is equal to `(x-1)!`.  So, `gamma(4.1) = 6.813` while `4.1! = 27.932`.  To get `4.1!` from `gamma(4.1)`, you can multiply `gamma(4.1)` by `4.1`, or simply take the gamma of `5.1` instead.  (I see no need to show a bunch of digits of precision here.)

In C#:

```cs
using MathNet.Numerics; //at beginning of program

private double Factorial(double x)
{
    double r = x;
    r *= SpecialFunctions.Gamma(x);
    return r;
    //This could be simplified into: 
    //return x * SpecialFunctions.Gamma(x);
}

private double Factorial2(double x)
{
    double r;
    r = SpecialFunctions.Gamma(x + 1);
    return r;
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to use `Math.Net`, you can write your own gamma function as follows:

```
static int g = 7;
static double[] p = {0.99999999999980993, 676.5203681218851, -1259.1392167224028,
 771.32342877765313, -176.61502916214059, 12.507343278686905,
 -0.13857109526572012, 9.9843695780195716e-6, 1.5056327351493116e-7};

Complex MyGamma(Complex z)
{
    // Reflection formula
    if (z.Real < 0.5)
    {
        return Math.PI / (Complex.Sin(Math.PI * z) * MyGamma(1 - z));
    }
    else
    {
        z -= 1;
        Complex x = p[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++)
        {
            x += p[i] / (z + i);
        }
        Complex t = z + g + 0.5;
        return Complex.Sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * (Complex.Pow(t, z + 0.5)) * Complex.Exp(-t) * x;
    }
}
```

Note that you can replace the data type `Complex` with `double` and the `Complex.` functions with `Math.` if you don't need complex numbers, like so:

```
double MyGammaDouble(double z)
{
    if (z < 0.5)
        return Math.PI / (Math.Sin(Math.PI * z) * MyGammaDouble(1 - z));
    z -= 1;
    double x = p[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++)
        x += p[i] / (z + i);
    double t = z + g + 0.5;
    return Math.Sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * (Math.Pow(t, z + 0.5)) * Math.Exp(-t) * x;
}
```

This is from an old wiki page (which has been replaced) but is copied [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gamma_function).